# Study the convergence of $\sum (1+1/n)^{n^2} x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find all the $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
> > \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2} x^n$ converges.

I'm stuck with the cases $x = \pm e^{-1}$. The only thing I could prove is $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2} e^{-n} \rightarrow 0$. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

Using $\log(x)>\frac{x-1}{x}$, we see that

$$\begin{align}
e^{-n}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}&=e^{-n}e^{n^2\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)}\\\\
&\ge e^{-n}e^{n^2/(n+1)}
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy-Hadamard, it converges within the radius $r=1/\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{(1+1/n)^{n^2}}=1/e$.

For values of $x=\pm r$, the general term of the series doesn't go to zero ( $|a_n|\to1/\sqrt e$).  Thus the series diverges.